# Unable to assign the instance to the delegate variable by directly inline construction

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, delegates, nsfilemanager

**Background**

some text files in a directory need to be removed, Filemanger is used for the task

**Simplified Code**

```
//First, create the fileManagerDelegate class
final class TextDeletionDelegate: NSObject, FileManagerDelegate {
  func fileManager _: FileManager, shouldRemoveItemAt url: URL) -> Bool {
    return url.lastPathComponent.contains("scene")
  }
}

//Delete all file with ".txt" extension name in the directory (marked as #1 in the code)

func getDocumentURLs() throws -> [URL] {
  return try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(
    at: documentDirectoryURL, // #1
    includingPropertiesForKeys: nil
  )
}

for url in try getDocumentURLs() {
  let fileManager = FileManager()
  let txtDeletionDelegate = TextDeletionDelegate() // problem trigger
  fileManager.delegate = txtDeletionDelegate // problem trigger
  try fileManager.removeItem(at: url)
}
```

So far so good, everything works fine until the two lines marked as "problem trigger" above has changed to the following style

```
for url in try getDocumentURLs() {
      let fileManager = FileManager()
      fileManager.delegate = TextDeletionDelegate() // error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
      try fileManager.removeItem(at: url)
    }
```

**What I've done**

I simply just don't want to create a local constant ***txtDeletionDelegate*** and assigned the inline constructed delegate object to the delegate variable of the custom fileManager instance by ***fileManager.delegate = TextDeletionDelegate()***

**Then what issue occurs**

I got the error message:

error: Playground execution aborted: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT).
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.

**Question**:

What happened? why I have to create a local constant and assign it to the delegate variable?

Comment: Your problem is probably that you delegate object is being released in the middle of being called since the filemanager will hold a weak reference to it and it will go out of scope as the loop iterates since it is a local object within the loop context. Since your function never changes you should simply create a delegate object *outside* the `for` loop and assign that instance as the delegate inside the loop. It is not necessary to keep creating new delegate objects.

Comment: @Paulw11 totally works, thanks a lot!